# Web process failed to bind to $PORT heroku deploy error with node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, mern

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy88Y.png)

I reread all the answers to a similar problem, but my problem is not solved.

- My MERN app tree:
  Weather-app:

  - client
  - dist/build
  - node_modules
  - server
  - babelrc
  - package.json
  - Procfile
  - server.js
  - webpack.config.js

Procfile:

```
web: npm start
```

Package.json

```
  "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack",
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --open && node server.js"
  },
```

server.js

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);



// Instantiate express
const app = express();

// Initialize routes middleware

app.use('/', require('./server/routes/user'));
app.use('/data', require('./server/routes/data'))
// Use express's default error handling middleware
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (res.headersSent) return next(err);
    res.status(400).json({ err: err });
});

// Start the server

app.listen(process.env.PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => {
});
```

webpack.config dev server

```
  devServer: {
    port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
    host: 'localhost',
    disableHostCheck: true,
    public: 'weather-mern.herokuapp.com',
    //Be possible go back pressing the "back" button at chrome
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: false,
    stats: 'minimal',
    publicPath: publicPath,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, publicPath),
    //hotmodulereplacementeplugin
    hot: true
  },
```

And in client/
I have request

How to change API_URL correclty?

```
const API_URL='http://localhost:3001'

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `${API_URL}/auth/login`,
        data: formData
    })
```

Comment: Was the process able to launch? Can you see anything in the Heroku logs? Also, does the thing you sent to Heroku need compiling or anything (babel, webpack etc.)? Cause Heroku won't do it for you.

Comment: the error occurs because you are trying to run to server on the same port number, you have to make a production build of your front end with webpack. Saw `npm run bs` on MERN docs

Comment: I added screenshot with error.
In package.json babel, webpack in dependecies .
Before heroku push i npm run build.
What about const API_URL?